# R - plumber, how to pass a value to the global environment?

Tags: r, plumber

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to pass a value, say the session pid, to the global environment with a plumber API?

I have tried the `<<-` operator, but doesn't work.

here's a really simple example :

(my_file.R)

```
#* @param x My argument
#* @get /lag_lead 
function(x){
 return(x*2)
 api_pid <<- Sys.getpid()
}
```

and the script to run the api :

```
library(plumber)
mon_api <- plumb('my_file.R')
mon_api$run(port = 8000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `return`-ing before the assignment, i.e. it does not take effect. Try

```
#* @param x My argument
#* @get /lag_lead 
function(x){
  api_pid <<- Sys.getpid()
  return(x*2)
}
```